# When do I write myFunction as opposed to myFunction() to call a function

Tags: javascript, function

I have seen, mostly in event handlers, functions called Pascal-style, i.e. without the brackets. Is there a difference between `myFunction` and `myFunction()`, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always use parentheses when you want to call a function.

The reason that you use it without parentheses when you want it to be a callback function is that you don't want to call the function when you assign it to the event. The event will call the function when the event is triggered.

You can pass a function reference around like any other value, and use parentheses when you want to call it. Example:

```
function test() {
  alert('test');
}

var x = test; // got the reference
var y = x; // copying it around
y(); // calling the function
```

Answer (score 0):

myFunction is function object and can be passed around like any other object / variable, usually as callback.
myFunction() invokes a function without any parameters and value of this expression is what myFunction function returns.

Pascal-style functions are not functions without brackets. Pascal-style functions represent function names that do not have first letter capitalized.
By some conventions only constructor functions should have first letter capitalized, because invoking a constructor function as a regular function (without new) and regular function as constructor can provoke serious bugs that are hard to find.

Comment: By Pascal style, I mean invoking a function with no parameters. If you look at some Pascal/Delphi code, you'll see that when a function with no parameters is called, there are no brackets.

Comment: I believe that in javascript, brackets are required to call a function, even if it doesn't have any parameters, otherwise function itself would be assigned to a variable, and not its return value.